# Find the general solution to $xy' = 2y + x^3e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to $xy' = 2y + x^3e^x$

Using the equation for the nonhomegenous ODE
$$y(x) = e^{-h}\left(\int e^hrdx + c \right)$$

I tried to solve this by dividing throughout by $x$ and collecting all terms in respect to $y$ on the LHS.

$$y' - \frac{2}{x}y =x^2e^x$$

Calculating for $h = \int P(x)dx$

from $y' + P(x)y = 0$ but because this is nonhomengeous we use the first equation and save the constant $c$ for later.  So we have next

$$h=-\int\frac{2}{x}dx=-\ln(\frac{2}{x}) = \ln(\frac{x}{2})$$
Then we have
$$e^h = \frac{x}{2} \implies e^{-h} = \frac{2}{x}$$

To find $e^hr$ I get that $\frac{x}{2}\cdot x^2e^x=\frac{1}{2}(x^3e^x)$

Plugging this all in
$$y(x) = \frac{2}{x} \left(\frac{1}{2}\int x^3e^x+c \right)$$

However this is far from the answer which is supposed to be $x^2(c+e^x)$, how was this derived?

Comment: Check the integral for $h$

Comment: @FormerMath I seem to be making lots of errors today ... Thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 1):

The integrating factor is
$$
\mu(x)=\exp\left(-\int \frac{2}{x}dx
\right)=\exp(-2\ln(x))=x^{-2}
$$
So
$$
yx^{-2}=\int e^xdx=e^x+c
$$
$$
y=x^2(e^x+c)
$$